# When is it appropriate to use class methods over instance methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

So.....? When is it?

I've written a mini example below but it doesn't seem to work as "potato squash" isn't showing. It's returning: "you are eating a *blank* type of food"

```
class Food

        def initialize(food=“none”)
            @food = food
        end

        def self.food=(food=“none”)

        end

        def self.type?
            puts “you are eating a #{food} type of food” # defines the type of food you are eating.
        end
    end 

Food.new("potato squash")
Food.type?
```

Thx in advanced guys.

Comment: [Brush up on OO before getting too deep](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22769/Introduction-to-Object-Oriented-Programming-Concep), it's worth it!

Answer (score 3):

None of your methods there should be class methods. Instance methods are used when you need to operate over data that is stored in an instance of a class. Class methods are used when you need to operate on data that pertains to that class.

For instance (no pun intended):

```
class Food
  def initialize(food="none")
    @food = food
  end

  # operating on data that is stored in this instance
  def type?
    puts "you are eating a #{@food} type of food"
  end

  # operating on data pertaining to this class
  def self.types
    return ['Fruits', 'Grains', 'Vegetables', 'Protein', 'Dairy']
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    class Food
        attr_accessor :food
        def initialize(food="none")
            @food = food
        end

        def type?
            puts "you are eating a #{@food} type of food"
        end
    end
```

So how to choose between them?

I'll ask myself: `@food`, what is your `type` versus `Food` what is your `type`. See which ones makes more sense.

Just to deviate from your food example:

Instance methods apply to those questions you want to ask from a particular object. You don't ask a `Person` class for its name, but you do so for a `@person` object.

On the other hand, you ask a `Person` class, say, `types_of_nationalities` which may return you an array of all the nationalities. But you would ask a `@person` what his `nationality` is.

Hope this clears things up a little.

Comment: True. Just thought that he should at least get some working code first. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code instead, since `type?` is an instance method. Instance methods only work on an instance of the Food class (such as `Food.new("potato squash")`):

```
f = Food.new("potato squash")
f.type?
```